# instantiate prefabs randomly over a polygon collider 2D bounds

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate trees over a mountain sprites randomly.
What I did is to add a polygon collider 2D component to the mountain sprite this generates a bounds.
I'm writing a script to instantiate tree (prefab) randomly over the mountain top edge.

My question is, how do I get the coordinates (positions) from that top bound of the polygon collider?

For example, if the size.x of this mountain polygon collider is 100.
in every 10 distance at x axis, I'd like to pick a y offset from its edge (bound), then place a tree to that position. so the bottom of the tree always at the edge of that mountain top

Therefore, I'm actually looking for a way to find the bounds y axis poistion by its related x axis position, say the total size.x of the collider is 100, when at x axix 50, how do I find its top edge y axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question at Unity form and got following answer, I believe the solutions is exactly what I was looking for, so I will answer my own question here, you can [click here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1718273/instantiate-prefabs-randomly-over-a-polygon-collid.html?childToView=1718610#answer-1718610) to get to the original post in Unity forum.

Solution:
Raycasting from above my object down is probably the easiest as it avoids complications if I change from a PolygonCollider and all the maths is done for me.

Basically the idea is, get the collider, find it's largest y value from the bounds, go up a little more, raycast directly downwards.

```html
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class TopPoint2D : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
     private new Collider2D collider;
 
     void Start()
     {
         collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
 
         Debug.Log(GetTopPoint(0));
         Debug.Log(GetTopPoint(1));
         Debug.Log(GetTopPoint(5));
         Debug.Log(GetTopPoint(10));
         Debug.Log(GetTopPoint(11));
     }
 
     private Nullable<Vector2> GetTopPoint(float xOffset){
         // a point on the y axis that is always above our collider
         float yStrictlyAbove = collider.bounds.max.y + 0.1f;
         
         float xMin = collider.bounds.min.x;
         
         float yStrictlyBelow = collider.bounds.min.y - 0.1f;
         float distance = yStrictlyAbove - yStrictlyBelow;
 
         RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(
             new Vector2(xMin + xOffset, yStrictlyAbove),
             Vector2.down,
             distance: distance
         );
 
         foreach(RaycastHit2D h in hits){
             if(h.collider == collider){
                 return new Nullable<Vector2>(h.point);
             }
         }
 
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get polygon points using *PolygonCollider2D.points* and store them into array of Vector 2.

Then Instantiate your trees on these points as you want. Like you said at every 10 points, make sure you take array value of every 10 point as in vec2[i] where i are 10, 20, 30,... The crucial part would be taking Instantiating at proper transform position. When you instantiate your tree, it will take center of the tree. You can change the pivot point of the tree to the bottom or take calculate offset point and use it.

Comment: tks for the reply, actually I'm not looking for points of the polygon collider because the distances between each point are different. I'm actually looking for a way to find the bounds y axis poistion by it's related x axis position, say the total size.x of the collider is 100, when at x axix 50, how do I find its top edge y axis?